# Failures in eventual consistent system and user experience

Tags: language-agnostic, user-experience, eventual-consistency

If I got it right, in an eventual consistent system you would accept and confirm events from a user, but really just keep the event in a queue, until it gets completely processed, including the effects becoming visible for the user.

But since in between by the very definition the system isn't 100% consistent, processing of the event might run into problems. As an example consider the event consisting of a change to an object which already got deleted.

What are patterns to present this kind of failure to the user?

The only thing I can come up with right now is a list of events, that still need processing, with markers about failures, but this seems to be a rather technical approach, that would probably by rather confusing for most users.

Comment: That's more of a Programmers question than an SO one IMO.

Comment: first time I vote for my own question to be closed as a duplicate :-P